# Looking for a safe converter to convert .mde file to .mdb

Tags: ms-access

do you know a safe converter to convert .mde file to .mdb ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Tony Toews article: [Create an Microsoft Access MDB from an MDE](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/createmdbfrommde.htm).

Also, [Convert an MDE to an MDB](http://www.pruittfamily.com/paul/MDE2MDB.htm)